# How TO Filter by _id in mongodb using pig

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a mongo documents like this:

```
db.activity_days.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b4ee617acf9ce0440a3185"),
    "aca" : 0,
    "ca" : 0,
    "cbdw" : true,
    "day" : ISODate("2014-12-10T00:00:00Z"),
    "dm" : 0,
    "fbc" : 0,
    "go" : 2500,
    "gs" : [ ],
    "its" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("551ac8d44f9f322e2b055d3a"),
            "at" : 2000,
            "atn" : "Running",
            "cas" : 386.514909469507,
            "dis" : 2.788989730832084,
            "du" : 1472,
            "ibr" : false,
            "ide" : false,
            "lcs" : false,
            "pt" : 0,
            "rpt" : 0,
            "src" : 1001,
            "stp" : 0,
            "tcs" : [ ],
            "ts" : 1418257729,
            "u_at" : ISODate("2015-01-13T00:32:10.954Z")
        }
    ],
    "po" : 0,
    "se" : 0,
    "st" : 0,
    "tap3c" : [ ],
    "tzo" : -21600,
    "u_at" : ISODate("2015-01-13T00:32:10.952Z"),
    "uid" : ObjectId("545eb753ae9237b1df115649")
}
```

I want to use pig to filter special _id range,I can write mongo query like this:

```
db.activity_day.find(_id:{$gt:ObjectId("54a48e000000000000000000"),$lt:ObjectId("54cd6c800000000000000000")})
```

But I don't know how to write in pig, anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `mongo-hadoop` connector for Pig, see [mongo-hadoop: Usage with Pig](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Pig-Usage#usage-with-pig).

Once you `REGISTER` the JARs (core, pig, and the Java driver), e.g., `REGISTER /path-to/mongo-hadoop-pig-<version>.jar;` via [grunt](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/Grunt) you could run:

```
SET mongo.input.query '{"_id":{"\$gt":{"\$oid":"54a48e000000000000000000},"\$lt":{"\$oid":"54cd6c800000000000000000}}}'
rangeActivityDay = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database.collection' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader()
DUMP rangeActivityDay
```

You may want to use [LIMIT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#limit) before dumping the data as well.

The above was tested using: `mongo-java-driver-3.0.0-rc1.jar`, `mongo-hadoop-pig-1.4.0.jar`, `mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.0.jar` and [MongoDB v3.0.9](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads#previous)